# Why will this while-loop not run?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm trying to learn while-loops in Javascript. Why won't this while loop run even when the button is clicked and the boolean becomes true? Is it even possible to have while-loops react to event-driven variable changes?

```js
let run = false;
let count = 0;


const button = document.getElementById("startstop");
const counter = document.getElementById("counter");

button.addEventListener('click', function() {

  run = !run; //clever way to toggle the boolean

})

while (run == true) {
  count++;
  counter.innerHTML = count;
}
```

```html
<button id="startstop">Start/Stop</button>

<p id="counter">0</p>
```

Comment: `while(run == true) { ... }` is executed before `run = !run`, so `run == true` evaluates as `false` and the loop is not executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop is not executed because run is false.

Here we can move the while to the button but that will not work because the tight loop does not give the DOM time to update.

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  run = !run; //clever way to toggle the boolean
  while (run) {
    count++;
    counter.innerHTML = count;
  }
})
```

I do NOT recommend to use while loops at all to update DOM

This will work but the loop will run even when not updating the counter

```js
let run = false;
let count = 0;


const button = document.getElementById("startstop");
const counter = document.getElementById("counter");

button.addEventListener('click', function() {

  run = !run; //clever way to toggle the boolean

})

setInterval(function() {
  if (!run) return
  count++;
  counter.innerHTML = count;
},10)
```

```html
<button id="startstop">Start/Stop</button>

<p id="counter">0</p>
```

A more elegant version would be to clearInterval

```js
let run = false;
let count = 0;
let tId;

const button = document.getElementById("startstop");
const counter = document.getElementById("counter");

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  run = !run; //clever way to toggle the boolean
  if (run) tId = setInterval(function() {
    count++;
    counter.innerHTML = count;
  }, 10)
  else clearInterval(tId)
})
```

```html
<button id="startstop">Start/Stop</button>

<p id="counter">0</p>
```

Comment: Hi! I like your answer but the working versions seems to ditch the while-loop entirely. Is a while loop not suitable for things like this?

Comment: @AndyBay Indeed it is not. JavaScript is single threaded and the while is too tight

Comment: And thanks for the like. I was upset that I got voted down because I missed the FIRST error (run was false) and only concentrated on the loop issue

Answer (score 1):

The while is running but when the page loads, so when you click on the button the while loop has already passed. You can see this in action when you place your while loop inside the click listener, however this is not the behaviour you want. Instead use an interval to fix this issue like shown below:

```js
let run = false;
let count = 0;
let interval = null;
const delay = 100;

const button = document.getElementById("startstop");
const counter = document.getElementById("counter");

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  run = !run;
  
  if (run === true) {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      count++;
      counter.innerHTML = count;
    }, delay)
    
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval)
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="startstop">Start/Stop</button>
<p id="counter">0</p>
```

Comment: Hi! This seems like a good answer in other aspects, but it removes the while loop entirely, which is the thing I'm trying to understand. Is it simply that a while loop is not suitable in situations in which you want to change the condition based on events?

Comment: Hi @AndyBay, Indeed while loops are not really suitable in this situation, instead while loops are more commonly used to loop over an array. For this situation it's the best to use interval since you can control how long it takes before the next iteration

Answer (score 0):

When you start up the page, the while loop actually ends the first time. When toggling the boolean, it will not automatically rerender the dom for you. So if you want to run the while loop, you'll need to wrap it in a function and call it.

PS Running this code will freeze your browser btw. Try adding in a delay

```js
let run = false;
let count = 0;

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  run = !run; //clever way to toggle the boolean
  doRun();
})

const doRun = () => {
   while (run) {
     count++;
     counter.innerHTML = count;
   }
}
doRun()
```

```html
<button id="startstop">Start/Stop</button>

<p id="counter">0</p>
```

Comment: You have forgotten to declare the dom variables

Answer (score 0):

The check `while (run == true) {` happens right after the event listener is added, at which points the value of `run` is still `false`.

Moreover a while loop that never stops is going to completely overwhelm the thread, making it impossible for the user to click the button.

You could use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval), which runs a function every x milliseconds.
That way, you can check the value of `run` whenever you want, without blocking the thread (which is what the `while (run == true) {` does).

```js
let run = false;
let count = 0;
let intervalID = setInterval(tick, 1000); // 1000ms = 1sec

const button = document.getElementById("startstop");
const counter = document.getElementById("counter");

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  run = !run;
  button.textContent = run ? "Stop" : "Start";
});

function tick() {
  if (run) {
    count++;
    counter.innerHTML = count;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="startstop">Start</button>

<p id="counter">0</p>
```

The problem with this is that you could be off by close to a whole second each time you restart the timer. To improve the time measuring you could instead use the variable `count` to store the actual milliseconds passed while the counter is on. Using another variable to store the timestamp at which the last measurement happened (or when the start button was last clicked) would also greatly improve the accuracy.

```js
let run = false;
let count = 0;
let previousTick = Date.now();
let intervalID = setInterval(tick, 100); // 100ms = 0.1sec

const button = document.getElementById("startstop");
const counter = document.getElementById("counter");

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  run = !run;
  button.textContent = run ? "Stop" : "Start";
  previousTick = Date.now();
});

function tick() {
  if (run) {
    count += Date.now() - previousTick;
    counter.innerHTML = Math.floor(count / 1000);
    previousTick = Date.now();
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="startstop">Start</button>

<p id="counter">0</p>
```